# Angular 2 multiple subscription

Tags: angular, api, angular2-services

Hello I'm developing an app that is gonna be deployed on an android device with a scanner device attached. I have developed the service part that gets the scanned data. My problem now is that I have to differenciate 3 api calls when the device start scanning. I'll explain myself better:

```
      scannedResult$ = new BehaviorSubject<Api1Response>(null);
      scannedResultApi2$ = new BehaviorSubject<Api2Response>(null);
      scannedResultApi3$ = new BehaviorSubject<Api2Response>(null);

      constructor(
        private scanData: ScanDataService,
        private api: ApiService,
        private scannedDestination: DestinationService
      ) {
        super();
        const scannedResult$ = this.scanData.scanResult$
        .pipe(
          filter(_ => this.scannedDestination.scanDestination === 'Api1'),
          tap(_ => (this.scanning = false)),
          switchMap(scanned=>
            this.api.callApi(Api1Query, {
              DataBar: scanned.DataBar
            })
          )
        )
      .pipe(
      filter(_ => this.scannedDestination.scanDestination === 'Api2'),
      tap(_ => (this.scanning = false)),
      switchMap(scanned =>
        this.api.callApi(Api2Command, {
          DataBar: scanned.DataBar
        })
      )
    )
    .pipe(
      filter(_ => this.scannedDestination.scanDestination === 'Api3'),
      tap(_ => (this.scanning = false)),
      switchMap(scanned =>
        this.api.callApi(Api3Command, {
          DataBar: scanned.DataBar
        })
      )
    )
    .subscribe(result => {
      this.scannedResult$.next(result);
    });
}
```

Inside `DestinationService` I have defined this:

```
scannedDestination: 'Api1' | 'Api2' | 'Api3';
```

And based on this scannedDestination I apply a filter to make different calls. 
My problem is that this solution doesn't work? Is it because I need to put three different subscriptions?
How can I make it work?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `switch/case` in `switchMap` if you want to do it in 1 subscription:

```
const scannedResult$ = this.scanData.scanResult$
        .pipe(
          tap(_ => (this.scanning = false)),
          switchMap(scanned=> {
            let apiCallType = '';
            switch(this.scannedDestination.scanDestination){
              case 'Api1':{
               apiCallType = Api1Query;
               break;
              },
              case 'Api2':{
               apiCallType = Api2Command;
               break;
              },
              case 'Api3':{
               apiCallType = Api3Command;
               break;
              }
            }
            return combineLatest(
                     this.api.callApi(apiCallType, {
                       DataBar: scanned.DataBar
                     }),
                     of(this.scannedDestination.scanDestination)
                   )
          })
        )
.subscribe(([result, apiType]) => {

       switch(apiType){
              case 'Api1':{
               this.scannedResult$.next(result);
               break;
              },
              case 'Api2':{
               this.scannedResultApi2$.next(result);
               break;
              },
              case 'Api3':{
               this.scannedResultApi3$.next(result);
               break;
              }
            }

});
```

**Edit Note:** I added `combineLatest` to pass `apiCallType` value with the subscription itself to choose which `BehaviorSubject` to invoke when subscription generates a value. Therefore, a second `switch/case` is added to the `subscribe` callback.

`combineLatest` should be imported like this: `import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';`

**Update 2**

As you asked in the comments, if you want to call another API (I assume it is an independent API call meaning it has nothing to do with the response) you can use `tap` from `rxjs`

```
       const scannedResult$ = this.scanData.scanResult$
        .pipe(
          tap(_ => (this.scanning = false)),
          switchMap(scanned=> {
            let apiCallType = '';

            let is2or3 = false; // flag to check if Api2Command or Api3Command

            switch(this.scannedDestination.scanDestination){
              case 'Api1':{
               apiCallType = Api1Query;
               break;
              },
              case 'Api2':{
               apiCallType = Api2Command;
               is2or3 = true;
               break;
              },
              case 'Api3':{
               apiCallType = Api3Command;
               is2or3 = true;
               break;
              }
            }


             let apiToCall = this.api.callApi(apiCallType, {
                       DataBar: scanned.DataBar
                     });

            if(is2or3){
                apiToCall = apiToCall.pipe(
                    tap(() => {
                         // do the other API call here.
                         // this.anotherApiCall();
                    })
                )
            }

            return combineLatest(
                     apiToCall,
                     of(this.scannedDestination.scanDestination)
                   )
          })
        )
       .subscribe(([result, apiType]) => {

           // same as above

        });
```

do/tap : https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html

Comment: hello thank you for the answer but they have different type: scannedResult$ = new BehaviorSubject<Api1Response>(null); scannedResultApi2$ = new BehaviorSubject<Api2Response>(null); scannedResultApi3$ = new BehaviorSubject<Api2Response>(null); Is it correct to subscribe like that?

Comment: If they are separate and different types of subjects, I think it is better to create 3 different subscriptions with 3 different filter pipes.

Comment: can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: When I was updating the answer, I saw that I misunderstood the actual problem. So, I improved the solution. Hope that helps.

Comment: I like it, I tried it but sadly I get "Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: [any, Number]) => void'.
  Type 'any[]' provides no match for the signature '(value: [any, Number]): void'."

Comment: In which line does it throw this error? And I also added parenthesis to wrap the arguments of `subscribe` callback.

Comment: with the parenthesis , the error is solved. Thank you, I shall do some tests

Comment: Quick question, if I wanted to call another API (let's call it ReloadApiCommand) once Api2Command or Api3Command are completed, how would I do that?

Comment: You can use `.pipe(tap(() =>{ makeAnotherApiCall(); }))`. Inside `switch/case`, put a boolean flag like `is2or3 = false` and set it to true in second and third cases. And after that, you can assign a variable `let apiToCall = this.api.callApi(......); if(is2or3){ apiToCall = apiToCall.pipe(....) }`. And in `combineLatest` put `apiToCall` instead of `this.api.callApi`.

Comment: could you please update the answer with this edit? thank you very much

Comment: thank you. So in the subscribe. the comment "same as above" means the code that were there before?

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, it is the same as the code before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190847/discussion-between-sebba23-and-harun-yilmaz).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
 const scannedResult$ = this.scanData.scanResult$
        .pipe(
          filter(_ => ),
          tap(_ => (this.scanning = false)),
          switchMap(scanned=>
            this.api.callApi(this.scannedDestination.scanDestination === 'Api1'? Api1Query: (this.scannedDestination.scanDestination === 'Api2'? Api2Command : Api3Command), {
              DataBar: scanned.DataBar
            })
          ).subscribe(result => {
      this.scannedResult$.next(result);
    });
```

Comment: hello thank you for the answer but it doesn't work because this: scannedResult$ = new BehaviorSubject<Api1Response>(null); scannedResultApi2$ = new BehaviorSubject<Api2Response>(null); scannedResultApi3$ = new BehaviorSubject<Api2Response>(null); they have different type